# How to securely store data? / How to securely encrypt a file?

Tags: file-encryption

**How do I safely encrypt a file?**

or formulated differentely:

**How do I safely store the data of my application in a file?**

Note: Using established tools isn't an option for this. The tasks need to be done at program level (using libraries and such).

Comment: Please note: the purpose of this Q &A is to have a reference wo which one can point people asking for the above two (or similar) questions. Thus this isn't a duplicate, nor is the question too broad, because we need a broad question + answer to answer every possible variation of this kind of question.

Comment: **If you want to vote this question, please read the above note and the answer below.** This question is held *very* broad with the purpose to serve for *a lot* of different question as a guide on how to accomplish the above two tasks. Other answers than the given one are possible if they reach the same level of completeness.

Comment: I am voting to close as too broad because, seeing the answer, it's clear that there's just too much stuff to say on the topic. Besides, the answer to the question as written is “[use an existing implementation such as dmcrypt, TrueCrypt, GPG, etc.](http://www.cs.berkeley.edu/~daw/teaching/cs261-f12/misc/if.html)”.

Comment: @Gilles, thank you for explaining the reasons for your vote. I truly appreciate this and try to do the same on every question I have to vote to close. To mitigate I may open a few new "questions" containing parts of this answer as answer (which seems indeed to be too large), so we can decide to redirect users to this (then probably closed) question or to the more specific ones.

Comment: Given the scope, I suggest a chat or meta discussion on the topic first. There's a lot of good material in your answer, but I fear that it's all packed so tightly that it's difficult to find the relevant parts for any given problem.

Comment: @Gilles, thank you for the suggestion, I opened [this](http://meta.crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/531/handling-broad-repetetive-quesions) on meta, as chat seems to be pretty "dead" on crypto.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Ask yourself **if you even can** securely store the user's data.
   This includes to check that the user won't get sniffed by the root / admin 
   user.
   Also make sure that your implementation is secure.
   Employ 
   standard code review mechanisms, make sure that your implementation has 
   countermeasures against timing attacks (like against AES).
   Also make sure 
   that you use appropriate data types.
   Using a byte* allocated using malloc 
   usually isn't very secure. **If your library provides mechanism for data 
   storage, use them!**
    Your OS may also provide means to protect data 
   while in memory, for example the data protection API in Windows only relies 
   on the current user and can be used to conceal sensible keys in memory. 
   Reading Schneier's Cryptography Engineering may be a very good idea for you, 
   to ensure you don't have side-channel leaks.
2. Ask yourself what you can use to **authenticate** the **user**. The 
   options are (it is explicitely allowed and recommended to **combine** as 
   many of them as convenience and availability allow):

   1. **Passwords**: Your user can supply a **password or a passphrase**. Do 
      not limit him in length of this, to allow him to use good and long 
      passphrases. This usually is a good choice, as it requires the user to know 
      something and this hence can not be lost like an usb-stick.
   2. **Keyfiles**: Allow the user to provide **keyfiles**. These files may 
      look arbitrary, but should be rare. **Allow the user** to use the 
      (cryptographical) random number generator of your application to **generate 
      strong keyfiles** (of 64 bytes length or more). Examples for **keyfiles** are **rare documents**, like **personal (word/) text documents** or **on-purpose generated files** just containing random data (created using the application's random number generator).
   3. **Custom Hardware**: If you are deploying in large scale you can force 
      the user to be required to use a **tamper-resistand hardware device**. This 
      device should support **symmetric encryption with a device-held key**.
   4. **User's Hardware**: Allow the user to use his **PKCS#11** or similar 
      smartcard or cryptographic token, which provides public key encryption, to 
      be used. Also allow the user to protect the key using the **TPM** (if 
      available)
   5. **OS data:** Allow the user to make the decryption dependant on 
      something stored in the current OS, like the **user credentials or OS 
      provided secure key storage**.
3. Inspect what **algorithms you have** at your disposal. You'll need (at 
   worst) five classes of algorithms: Password-based key derivation functions, 
   encryption algorithms, modes of operation, message authentication codes and 
   cryptographically secure random number generators.
   **At the time of 
   writing the following algorithms are recommended (in descending order). If 
   functionality is already provided more top-level don't use it.**

   1. **Cryptographically secure random number generators**:

      1. **[Fortuna](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fortuna_%28PRNG%29)**
      2. An **approved algorithm**. This may either be the result of a 
         contest or some approved algorithm by some trusted institute (e.g. **ANSSI, 
         NIST, BSI**, ...). **Avoid algorithms with "provable" security where the 
         institute provides the parameters**, these parameters may be chosen on 
         purpose to get back-door access. For **seeding** use the cryptographically 
         secure random number generator of your **OS**. They are usually a bit 
         hidden.
      3. Some "weak" standard approach. (i.e. run a blockcipher in **CTR 
         mode** and delete key and IV as soon as possible) Get the **key and the IV** 
         from the cryptographically secure random number generator of your **OS**. 
         They are usually a bit hidden.
   2. **Password based key derivation functions:**

      1. The winner of the **PHC-competition**. If there are multiple 
         winners, ask for the differences and use the one most suited for your needs.
      2. **scrypt**
      3. **bcrypt**
      4. **PBKDF2**, using an efficient and secure hash function (on your 
         platform)
      5. implement your own PBKDF2!
   3. **Ciphers**:

      1. The winner of the **CAESAR**-competition (2018+). If there are 
         multiple winners, ask for the differences and choose the appropriate one.
      2. **AES**. Note: For data that needs to be confidential unti 2070 or 
         earlier, it is recommeded to use AES-128. In every else case use AES-192 or 
         AES-256.
      3. **ChaCha**(preferred) or **Salsa20**.
      4. One of the following three: **Threefish, Serpent or Twofish**
      5. **3DES** with 3 keys. (needs 168 bits of keying material)
   4. **Modes of operation** (this is obsolete for CAESAR-winners):

      1. **OCB** (If the patent has expired)
      2. **GCM**
      3. **EAX** (preferred) or **CCM**
      4. **CTR**, below this a message authentication code is required 
         (including)
      5. One of the following: **CFB or OFB**
      6. **ECB**, avoid at all cost, rather implement your own CTR!
   5. **Message authentication codes**:

      1. **Poly-1305** using a standardized construction
      2. **HMAC**, using a secure standardized hash function, preferably 
         **SHA-3** or a member of the **SHA-2** family. **Encrypt the data first, 
         then authenticate the ciphertext!**
      3. implement your own HMAC!
4. Ask yourself on how to **design the header**. The header should contain:

   - The **salt**, a **random** 64 byte or more value that will be newly 
     chosen on each single creation of a new file. This will be fed into the 
     password-based key derivation function. The salt can be **open**, but may be 
     authenticated using the authentication mechanism.
   - The **parameters** for the password-based key derivation function. 
     These parameters need to be **open**. They should be chosen such that key 
     derivation needs approximiately **100ms to 1s** on the target platform. A 
     value indicating the password based key derivation function used is 
     considered a parameter.
   - A **nonce or an IV** for the cipher / mode. This value should be chosen 
     at random and be stored **open**ly.
   - The remainder of the header should be **encrypted and 
     authenticated**.
     The before-mentioned nonce/IV should be used along with 
     the key derived from the password using the password-based key derivation 
     function and the stored salt and parameters.
   - The **master-keys** for the data part of the file. These should be 
     random and maximal length. This is part of the **encrypted part** of the 
     header
   - A **nonce / IV** for the data part. This value should be random. This 
     value can (and should) be part of the **encrypted part** of the header.
5. **The actual data is now encrypted using the above chosen 
   cipher/mode/authentication triple and the key/IV/nonce pair of the encrypted 
   part of the header.**

**Now some question that may arise**:

1. **Is it worth it to use multiple-encryption?**
   **No.**
   The benefit 
   by double encryption is only 1-bit due to the meet-in-the-middle attack. 
   Streamciphers may be combined easier, but it is absolutely unneccessary as 
   all ciphers are unbreakable for the forseeable future (50 years+)
2. **What authentication methods should I use?**
   **As many as possible, 
   but at least password**
   You need to have a very good reason not to use 
   passwords because everything else can be attacked with admin rights or can 
   be stolen.
3. **You didn't mention the other four authentication methods in the header 
   part, how should I incorporate them?**

   2. **Keyfiles**: Assume that each keyfile has low entropy. That being 
      said, you can't really do alot against it. Derive a key from every keyfile 
      using some digest-expansion function and your favorite secure hash function 
      (SHA-2/3) and construct a big XOR consisting of all file's hashes and the 
      user's password. This would look like this: $Key = PBKDF(PW) \oplus H
      (File_1) \oplus H(File_2) \oplus ...$, where $\oplus$ denotes bitwise XOR.
   3. **Custom Hardware**: At the creation of the file let the device 
      generate a symmetric key that will be kept inside the device. Perform 
      everything up to the keyfile / password level (see directly above point) and 
      then send this to the device for encryption. The key being used doesn't have 
      to be unique for each file. It is suggest that one key is being used for all 
      files. It is also possible to add an identifier to the file to identify the 
      associated hardware key.
   4. **User's Hardware**: Let the device generate an OpenPGP key or a valid 
      S/MIME encryption certificate. Send the key being the result of the step 
      directly above (or 2 steps above) to the device for decryption. It will 
      decrypt it and return the key used to decrypt the master-keys.
   5. **OS data**: If you have user credentials (maybe some random strings), 
      hash them and incorporate them at the same time in the same way as the 
      keyfiles. If your OS provides you secure storage (or your TPM does), store a 
      key and pass it in as "keyfile", thus hash it and incorporate it in the XOR 
      step.
4. **Should I use an open source library or some closed-source library?**
   **Open-Source**
   Chances are very good that there aren't any security 
   issues in well-known open-source libraries, whereas closed source puts 
   restriction in regard of when you can use it, usually you have to pay to be 
   able to use and you can't usually inspect the code on your own to make sure 
   it's secure.
5. **Why did you use XOR to include keyfiles?**(relates to question 3)
   **Convenience.**
   If 
   you don't use something that is commutative, like XOR, users will run into 
   problem because files have to be supplied in the exact same order. This gets 
   even harder if files are just re-named but their contents are kept. And from 
   a security perspective this is no less secure as one basically constructs a 
   "stream cipher" with the password based key derivation function output, the 
   hashes of the keyfiles and the other outputs (TPM, credentials,...) which is secure as 
   long as one source is secure.

Comment: If anyone knows anything that relates to this, please comment and I'll incorporate. (like other means of authentication, other possible questions, ...). Note: biometrical stuff is excluded because it relies on software-driven access control, because of slght variation the measured data each time.

Comment: "implement ur own PBKDF ?" or "HMAC" , not sure if its good idea ? definitely not

Comment: @sashank This is meant, provided that you have a crypto library providing hash functions, PBKDF2 and HMAC are relatively easy to implement. But this case should be extremely rare. I'll add "implement your CTR" instead of ECB.

Comment: Doing your own custom crypto is usually not so good advice . https://www.schneier.com/blog/archives/2015/05/amateurs_produc.html

Comment: @sashank, I'm aware of "don't roll your own crypto", but I think recommending **highly standardized easy and secure mechanism** for self-implementation is still alot better than "don't authenticate at all" or "just use plain hash / plain passwords for keys". HMAC and PBKDF2 are RFC'ed and hence there's is **easy** documentation available, for those to implement it themselves. However **every single crypto library** I'm aware of supplies HMAC and PBKDF2 or better mechanism, so it would be a really bad (pre-90s! I think) library if it doesn't provide the two.

Comment: Ok. Also it is not clear the XORING of key files ?

Comment: @sashank, did the edit clarify thinks? I'm not sure what you're asking. Do you ask "Where the hell is XOR used?" or more something like "Why the hell do you XOR key files and not their hashes (in relation to Q5)?"

Comment: first , what is a keyfile ? is it a general file with cryptographic keys ? then why dont we just call it keys ?

Comment: @sashank by point 2 of point 2, a keyfile is a user-supplied file, that is rare (and hence provides entropy) and may be generated using a CSPRNG. I extended this point a bit.